# reducing list based on fuzzy values in python

Tags: python

I have a list that contains groups of nearly identical numeric values. i.e. (1004.523, 1004.575, 1004.475, 791.385, 791.298, 791.301, 791.305, 791.299)

What I am trying to do is read through the list and find all the 1004.5 +- values aggregate them and find the average value. then continue on and find all the 791.0 +- values and do the same to them.

I do not know how many individual values there will be in each "group" nor do I know how many groups there will be.

The result I am looking for is another list which would contain the average values of each of the groups. So in the example my result would be (1004.524, 791.3176)

The code I'm currently using is very Kludgey and it seems there should be a much better way to do it.

As you can see I have to repeat code twice once in the else and once at the end of the if since the last set of numbers does not trigger the else. Plus at the completion of the if I need to add the last value.

If I use the len(tones) rather that len(tones)-i I get an out of range error.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Ed

```
    toneLen = len(tones) -1
    for i in range(0, toneLen):
        if abs(tones[i]-tones[i+1]) <= 2.0:
            tmpTones.append(tones[i])
        else:
            freq = mean(tmpTones)
            newTones.append(freq)
            tmpTones = []
    tmpTones.append(tones[i+1])
    freq = mean(tmpTones)
    newTones.append(freq)                
    tones = newTones
```

**UPDATE:**
First I wanted to thank everyone who submitted suggestions. The response was very quick and helpful. I should have probably included some more info which I am doing below. Thanks so much for your help.

Second , a quick explanation of what I am trying to do. Our local Fire Department is looking for a way to track dispatches for departments close to them. For the most part they use two tone sequential paging i.e. 1000Hz followed by 500Hz.

So I am using numpy fft to find the tone frequency. Since the accuracy of the tone appears to be about +- 2 Hz, I compare the calculated frequency to a list of known paging tones and pick the closest match. After all the tones have been matched to the paging tones I look for matches to departments of interest.

One thing I did not know when I started this that in any given dispatch the same tone can be repeated several times, so the order of the tones is important. An example:
707.3, 339.6, 707.3, 569.1, 447.2, 569.1 would be a typical dispatch. I then look to see if any of the tone pairs are ones I'm interested in if so I display a message

Thanks again for all your help.

Ed

Comment: Do you know how "wide" the groups can be (i.e. did you pull that `2.0` out of the air, or is it something that can be reasoned out)? Could the groups "overlap"? Like could there be a huge series of constantly-increasing values a small amount apart, covering a large range?

Comment: From looking at the numbers I found that in general they tend to be +-2Hz. These numbers are a result of sampling from a sound card. I am currently sampling at 7 times per second and then doing the fft calculations to determine the dominant frequency. In general the first tone is 1 second long or about 7 samples the second tone is about 3 seconds long or about 21 samples. There are usually more than one set of tones, so the pattern will repeat itself. I have never heard more than six sets of tones at once so in general I would say that 200 is probably a practical limit.

Comment: Thanks for the added information on your exact problem, it helps. My solution wouldn't work for example, since it reorders the samples. One question, wouldn't it be simpler to classify the tones before you try to count them up? It's a lot easier to match up exact equivalents than approximate ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds the borders between groups of nearly identical values and then computes the mean using slices on the original list.

```
tones = (1004.523, 1004.575, 1004.475, 791.385, 791.298, 791.301, 791.305, 791.299)
splits = [i for i in range(1, len(tones)) if abs(tones[i-1] - tones[i]) > 2]
splits = [0] + splits + [len(tones)]
tones = [mean(tones[splits[i-1]:splits[i]]) for i in range(1, len(splits))]
# [1004.5243333333333, 791.31759999999997]
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. It works beautifully. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for [kmeans clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

In the code below, I use [scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html) to cluster the data into `k` groups.
If the distortion is greater than some set threshold amount, then we increase `k` by one, and redo the kmeans clustering. We repeat until we find groups whose total distortion is less than the `threshold` amount.

```
import scipy.cluster.vq as scv
import numpy as np
import collections
def auto_cluster(data,threshold=0.1):
    # There are more sophisticated ways of determining k
    # See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set
    k=1
    distortion=1e20
    while distortion>threshold:
        codebook,distortion=scv.kmeans(data,k)
        k+=1   
    code,dist=scv.vq(data,codebook)    
    groups=collections.defaultdict(list)
    for index,datum in zip(code,data):
        groups[index].append(datum)
    return groups

data=np.array((1004.523, 1004.575, 1004.475, 791.385, 791.298, 791.301, 791.305, 791.299))
groups=auto_cluster(data)    
for index in groups:
    print('{index}: ave({d}) = {ave}'.format(
        index=index,
        d=','.join(map('{0:g}'.format,groups[index])),
        ave=np.mean(groups[index]))
        )
```

yields

```
0: ave(791.385,791.298,791.301,791.305,791.299) = 791.3176
1: ave(1004.52,1004.58,1004.48) = 1004.52433333
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered this. I has been many many years since I took a math class of any kind. Unfortunately in my original question I failed to mention that the same tone could happen more than once, and that tone order is crucial. However your idea did solve another problem I was working on, and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what numbers may appear in the sequence, you can use this (`exacttones` is expected values list):

```
tones = (1004.523, 1004.575, 1004.475, 791.385, 791.298, 791.301, 791.305, 791.299)
exacttones = (1004.5, 791.3)
limit = 0.2
[sum(x)/len(x) for x in [[y for y in tones if abs((y-e))<=limit] for e in exacttones]]
# [1004.5243333333333, 791.31759999999997]
```

To analyze the sequence without knowing the `exacttones`, something like this will work:

```
def calc(d, value):
    for k in d:
        if abs(k-value) <= limit:
            d[k].append(value)
            return d
    d[value] = [value]
    return d
[sum(x)/len(x) for x in reduce(calc, values, {}).values()]
# [1004.5243333333333, 791.31759999999997]
```

Comment: OP says """nor do I know how many groups there will be""" -- `exacttones` is cheating.

Comment: I actually do have a list of known valid tones (about 130). I am going to experiment with this idea to see if it is workable because it would combine 2 steps into 1. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @edwardb glad to help. I would appreciate any input about it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

This does without the intermediate temp list:

```
assert tones
total = prev = tones[0]
count = 1
newlist = []
for i in xrange(1, len(tones)):
    t = tones[i]
    if abs(t - prev) <= DELTA:
        total += t
        count += 1
        prev = t
    else:
        newlist.append(total / count)
        total = prev = t
        count = 1
newlist.append(total / count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I do appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a list of audio tones, you probably want to use a fraction such as [1.059](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note#Accidentals) to determine the range to assign to a group, rather than hard-coding a number like `2.0`.

```
def average_tones(tones):
    threshold = 1.059
    average = 0
    count = 0
    for tone in sorted(tones):
        if count != 0 and tone >= average*threshold:
            yield average
            count = 0
        average = (average * count + tone) / (count + 1)
        count += 1
    if count != 0:
        yield average
```

Comment: I would be very interested to know why you suggest a fraction for the range. I picked 2.0 because it seemed to match the data I was seeing. Is there a reason the fraction would be better? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @edwardb, if the range of frequencies is small enough or your clustering is tight enough, a constant might work as well as a multiplier. My constant has a link, click through and you'll see where I picked my number from - it's the multiplier for a semitone difference. In retrospect I should have picked 1.0295 to halve the range on either side of the center frequency.